# How to enable large data output on python jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using mysql database with jupyter notebook to execute some query. When I run these query in msql workbench I get multiple rows result but in jupyter notebook I just get first 4-5 rows result.

I tried 
pd.set_option("display.max_rows",101)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 999 
to increase the max rows but it did not work. 
Any other suggestion?
[mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3ag5.jpg)
[jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzCU3.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Displaying only the first five rows is typical for usage of `pd.Dataframe.head()`, which I would claim, is called inside your function `executeQueryAndShowResults`, which you do not show. Usually, jupyter notebook prints the full dataframe (i.e.) all rows, by simply typing the dataframe name and executing the cell.

I recommend adjusting your function to return a dataframe like this

```
def executeQueryAndShowResults(query):

    # executing query ...
    # Here is written what is coded in your function body...

    # df.head()           # I assume/claim that there is a statement like this printing the first five rows of the dataframe. Comment this
    return df             # Instead, Return the dataframe
```

In Jupyter Notebook, call your function then like that

```
df1 = executeQueryAndShowResults(query)    # saving returned dataframe
df1                                        # printing returend dataframe
```